# how to check if user exist in quickblox android api?

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm developing an android application using quickblox, i try to check if a usr exist using his phone number. Api return no errors, but return 0 for users found. I check phone number in quickblox panel and is present...what's the problem?

**SOLVED:
Solved, the problem was "+" i encode like an URL and now works!**

here is an image about my panel with phone namer for user:

[image]

here is my code:

```
numero = "+393482222222";
              Log.v("Numero:", "-"+numero+"-");
              QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
              pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
              pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(5);

              ArrayList<String> usersphone = new ArrayList<String>();
              usersphone.add(numero);

                QBUsers.getUsersByPhoneNumbers(usersphone, pagedRequestBuilder, new QBCallbackImpl() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Result result) {
                        if (result.isSuccess()) {

                            QBUserPagedResult usersResult = (QBUserPagedResult) result;
                            ArrayList<QBUser> users = usersResult.getUsers();

                            Log.v("Found start chat", "start chat");

                            if (usersResult.getUsers().size() > 0) {

                                //  Apri la chat
                                //
                                appDelegate.sh.setOpponentId(usersResult.getUsers().get(0).getId());
                                appDelegate.sh.setOpponentNumber(numero);

                                avviaChat();
                            } else {

                                sendSMS();

                            }

                        } else {

                            Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: did you try to use without +?

Comment: yes, i try but i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Simone.
If returned answer is "error entity you are looking for was not found" - it's mean user doesn't exist. Check your code and user's mail. Try another methods from quickblox like:

```
QBUsers.getUserByLogin( yourlogin, QBCallback) or
QBUsers.getUsersByFullName(fullName, QBCallback)
```

Comment: ok, but login is the login string of QBUSER? is right? why you ask me about mail?

Comment: If you are still getting this error you can add comment to quickblox team on http://quickblox.com/developers/Android

Comment: Solved, the problem was "+" i encode like an URL and now works